# JSch: how to set environment variables for remote host on a ChannelShell?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am experimenting with the JSch and JCTerm library from JCraft. While the principal terminal emulation works quite well, I have some issues getting an environment variable to the remote host.

This is a code snippet, that creates the session to the remote host and opens a channel which provides the input and output streams.

```java
JSchSession sessioon = JSchSession.getSession("root", "mypasswd", "targethost", 22, userInfo, null);
Channel channel = session.getSession().openChannel("shell");
((ChannelShell)channel).setEnv("LC_ALL", "en_US");
channel.connect();

// create JCTermSwing terminal emulation GUI
```

The line `setEnv(...)` seems to have no effect, as the environment variable `LC_ALL` is not set on the remote host.

The goal I want to achieve is to set the character encoding to "en_US" on the remote host. This will work around the fact, that JSch seems not to be able to handle German umlauts correctly.

Does someone have any insight into how to set the variable? Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you check that LC_ALL is not set ?

Comment: When the terminal emulation rendered by the JCTermSwing class is finally displayed, I can issue the `locale` command. In its output, LC_ALL has no value. And German umlauts are displayed as Chinese characters.

Comment: Maybe you should check that environment variable are exported with a less complicated test (try an ``echo $LC_ALL`` or a ``System.getEnv("LC_ALL")``

Comment: To my knowledge, environment variables are not shared between multiple ssh sessions. But I also did a `echo $LC_ALL` as soon as the terminal emulation has started and the variable was empty.
I don't get the `System.getEnv("LC_ALL")` part. I do not run Java code on the remote host.